# Cant access mongodb shell and mongo errored

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

I installed mongo following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) tutorial with the exception that I ran the service with pm2 because I can actually tell what I am doing with pm2.

I then have been trying to follow [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) tutorial however I cant even access the shell.

I have tried the following commands and none of them work:

`./bin/mongo` causes a file not found error whether it is in my project file or in the `/var/lib/mongodb` folder where the db is supposedly "installed"

Additionally

```
mongo localhost:27017 (or just mongo)
```

causes

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: test
2018-02-12T20:15:59.009+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2018-02-12T20:15:59.009+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

My log file (from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log) can be found [here](https://paste.ee/p/0peEd). I do have some confusion about it:

1. Why did it shut down
2. Why is the host=GraphicsApplications? That is an old folder that I have since deleted on my machine. It was my first attempt at getting this going but back then I was hosting my DB with mlab. The folder/name it lists no longer exists. For some reason though the start of every line in terminal says root@GraphicsApplications. Not sure where that name came from... perhaps I named the box that?

Ultimately I dont know exactly how that tutorial had me install mongodb. Sure I installed the packages and everything but I dont feel like I ever really created anything if that makes sense.

It is worth noting that pm2 does show the status of the mongod app as "errored" currently but I am not sure why or for how long it stayed up.

I am just trying to get my database running on my own Linux box rather than mlab. I had everything working with mlab but now want to be hosting my db on localhost.

Comment: Do you get anything if you run this from the command line? 

sudo service mongod start

Comment: Yes that command generates the same errors. Additionally it has this message if you ask for its status after starting it: https://paste.ee/p/7sWHx

Comment: Looking at the logs Mongo starts up ok but your hostname is then causing it to crash. Could you $ cd /etc and open hosts, then post whats in there

Comment: I think this is it: https://paste.ee/p/cI7pf

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding file not found:**

Try running from the cmd line:

```
which mongo
```

If that doesn’t show any result then the mongo binariesarn’t in your PATH env variable, in which case try

```
find / -name “mongo*”
```

That should then show where your mongo binaries have been installed.

If you know where the binaries are installed then running:

```
./bin/mongo
```

Presumes you’re in the mongo home dir, so you would need to run;

```
/var/lib/mongodb/bin/mongo
```

**Regarding connection refused**

could be an iptables rule, try disabling it and starting mongo

```
 sudo ufw disable
```

**hostfile**

Comment out this

```
127.0.1.1 GraphicsApplications
```

And change/add this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

As per : https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-20952

Comment: It is strange `which mongo` returns `/usr/bin/mongo` however I cannot cd into that folder

Comment: Ok so the folder that gets returned for where mongo (usr/bin/mongo) does not seem to exist. usr/bin exists but does not contain anything with mongo in its name. However the /var/lib/mongodb folder does exist howeve there is no bin, mongo, or usr file or folder inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the logs it says that your hostname is `host=GraphicsApplications`
But in your actual hosts file you have `127.0.1.1 GraphicsApplications GraphicsApplications`

Edit this line in your hosts file to be just `127.0.1.1 GraphicsApplications`

Then save the file and rerun `mongod`. Hopefully that should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it. How can I confirm that mongo is using that file? I did try it with and without the line about 127.0.0.1 with no luck on either try.

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling it as per the docs rather than with pm2

Comment: I did try it without pm2 with no change. Pm2 does not install it but just manage the mongod app. The result is the same using other app managers.